# Login systems with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When a user logs in, how do I get all of their mysql information? I have a registering system and login system. When they log in they type their username and password, those are the only two variables i can use, because they type them in. How do I get all the other variables, not typed in by the user, for that profile?
Their usernames are unique. How do i get the rest of their variables to use throughout all of my php files?

My login file:

```
<?
/*Use of Sessions*/
if(!session_id())
session_start();

header("Cache-control: private"); //avoid an IE6 bug (keep this line on top of the page)

$login='NO data sent';

/*simple checking of the data*/
if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{

/*Connection to database logindb using your login name and password*/
$db=mysql_connect('localhost','teachert_users','dogs1324') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('teachert_users');

/*additional data checking and striping*/
$_POST['login']=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['login'])));
$_POST['pass']=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['pass'])));
$_POST['pass']=md5($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['pass']=strrev($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['pass']=md5($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['pass'].=$_POST['pass'];
$_POST['pass']=md5($_POST['pass']);


$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='{$_POST['login']}' AND     password='{$_POST['pass']}'",$db) or die(mysql_error());

/*If there is a matching row*/
if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
    $login='Welcome back, '.$_SESSION['login'];
    $login.='</br> we are redirecting you.';
echo $login;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL=/php/learn/selectone.php">';    
    exit;    

}
else
{
    $login= 'Wrong login or password';
}

mysql_close($db);

}

//you may echo the data anywhere in the file
echo $login;

?>
```

I can use their login and password in all other files with the $_SESSION['var'];
How do i get the rest? Like their age? or their Name? or any variable stored in my mysql files.
Yes i know MD5 isn't the best, let's not turn this into a discussion on that.

------------------------edit-------------------------------
I guess i'll rephrase that:

I use this:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='{$_POST['login']}' AND password='{$_POST['pass']}'",$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

How do i get variables from that particular user/profile. Like their other variables, such as their name, which in my mysql is fname.

-------------------------Edit---------------------------
I have updated to:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'teachert_users', 'dogs1324', 'teachert_users');
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error connecting to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$user = $_SESSION['login'];
$get_user_info_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username = '$user'");
if($get_user_info_query->num_rows) {
    while($get_user_info_row = $get_user_info_query->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($get_user_info_row['math']) {   
       print_r($get_user_info_row['math']);
        }        
    }
} else {
    echo 'User not found';
}
```

but the print_r still prints all of the user's information. not just the math information. Why?

Comment: For a decently safe login system, save each login session in your db. for each page request, compare session id and IP with your session table, then you can at the same time load other user data from your users table. And don't use deprecated mysql_* functions

Comment: For a decently safe login system, don't do it yourself. Take a library that does it for you and that has been proven reliable.

Comment: @jtheman  please answer the question?

Comment: @ic2817 that's not really my quetion.

Comment: That was not an answer but a comment. But I agree with lc2817, use an existing library.

Comment: fetch your query and loop through the array to recieve the desired values

Comment: @RoyalBg can you show an example? and make an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try using `mysqli` or `pdo`, `mysql_*`  functions are oficially deprecated

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbmanager, $dbpass, $dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error connecting to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli-    >connect_error;
}
$user = $_SESSION['login'];
$get_user_info_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username = '$user'");
if($get_user_info_query->num_rows) {
    while($get_user_info_row = $get_user_info_query->fetch_assoc()){
        print_r($get_user_info_row);
    }
} else {
    echo 'User not found';
}
```

this will print the entire row information returned by mysql so to use one specific field use `$get_user_info_row['username']` inside the `while` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much. Mucho Gracias.  One thing, you forgot a ".

Comment: try `if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login'])) {$user = $_SESSION['login']; //move the mysql query here} else { echo 'User not found'; }

Comment: I did add the $get_user_info_row['username']. and it actually still places all of them.

Comment: have you removed this line `print_r($get_user_info_row);` ? the php `print_r()` command prints the content of an array so `$get_user_info_row` this array contains the user info as is in mysql table so you have to remove this line and use only the info you need like this `$get_user_info_row['column_name'];` and remove the `print_r()` line that is just to see what exactly is returning mysql after fetching its response

Comment: I've read your edit, you have to replace the `print_r()` so if you only want to print that column just do an `echo` not an `print_r()` for example `echo $get_user_info_row['fname'];` or assign this value to another variable `$fname = $get_user_info_row['fname']; so with that you can use the same value outside the `while` statement

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to get data information using the mysql_ approach:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
```

The variable $row will have an array with the fields returned by the sql statement. Use this line after check if the exist rows.

Try to run

`print_r($row)`

and you will see it contents.

Answer (score 0):

First, [custom encryption routines are not considered secure](http://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram-0205.html), especially if you post your code (or a variant of it) here.

Second, your routine has no extra security over a plain MD5 (which is considered horribly insecure). Let's say your routine takes 3x longer than a plan MD5. Big deal, you can do [a billion MD5s per second](https://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=6616), so at best you've added a few seconds to the attacker's cracking time when trying the 1 billion most common passwords.

You should never try to roll your own password routines. In fact, you shouldn't be rolling your own user login and session code either. Use a framework like CakePHP. (You may need a plugin for the User Auth stuff. Make sure it uses bcrypt().)

When you use a framework, you will benifit from having lots of pre-existing examples and "best practices". You'll be programming at a higher level. In fact, frameworks often provide protection against attacks you don't even know about, like SQL injection, XSS, etc.